# How do I change a banner image when hovering over thumbnail navigation using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, slider, banner

I inherited a website build from another developer and he has built an image slider on the homepage which basically cycles through five images and there's thumbnail navigation along the bottom of the slider whereby the thumbnails highlight when the corresponding large image is visible in the slider viewport.

He's done it as a completely custom job using HTML, PHP and jQuery which possibly is a better solution to using a pre built slider with modifications(?).

The functionality as it is doesn't allow for any kind of paging function so you have to wait for the slides to continue to fade if there's any particular content you wish to view (not cool). In addition, the thumbnails when clicked go to inner pages within the site instead of showing the corresponding slide.

What I'm trying to achieve is basically keeping the slider rotating automatically but making the main image change (with fade) when HOVERING over any of the thumbnails and then i'd like to get the click event on the thumbnail to link to the inner page. When the mouse hover leaves the thumbnail I'd like the slider to continue automatically from that point.

Is this a simple fix on the below code? Should I completely rip this apart and start from scratch? Are there any prebuilt sliders that allow for this functionality either out-of-the-box or with small modifications?

I have looked at various sliders with thumbnail nav's but they seem to need a click event on the thumbnail to change the slide.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - also an opinion on the methods of the slider would be great too as I'm not convinced inserting background images using jQuery is the best way to build this.

Code is below (apologies for how much there is - I'm also not convinced on the div naming structure!):

```
<?php
// set the array for the values to change etc.
$post_ids = array(6,8,10,124,135);
$links = array(
'title 1',
'title 2',
'title 3',
'title 4',
'title 5',);
$sub_header = array(
'sub title 1',
'sub title 2',
'sub title 3',
'sub title 4',
'sub title 5');
$banner_large_small_images = array(
'thumb title 1',
'thumb title 2',
'thumb title 3',
'thumb title 4',
'thumb title 5');
$banner_content = array(
'description text 1',
'description text 2',
'description text 3',
'description text 4',
'description text 5');
?>
<!-- javascript for banner with fader -->
<script type="text/javascript">

        (function($) {

            $(document).ready(function() {
// Load the first image and set the first content //
$('#banner-to-go').css('opacity', '0');
$('#banner-to-go').css("background-image", "url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home-tabs/<?php echo $banner_large_small_images[0];?>_largeheader.jpg)") + $("#banner-text-container").html('<?php echo '<h2>'.$links[0].'<br /><span>'.$sub_header[0].'</span></h2><p>'.$banner_content[0].'</p>';?>');


<?php
// loop through the css buttons
$count_array = count($links); // should be 5 for banners;
$i = 0;
$i2 = 1;
while ($i <= ($count_array - 1)) 
{
    // check for the first value
    if ($i == 0)
    {
    ?>
        $('#button_banner_<?php echo  $i2; ?>').css("background-image", "none)");
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
        $('#button_banner_<?php echo  $i2; ?>').css("background-image", "url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home-tabs/<?php echo $banner_large_small_images[$i];?>_smallheader.jpg)");
    <?php
    }
    $i++;
    $i2++;
}
?>

$('#banner-to-go').fadeTo("slow", 1);

<?php
// loop through the values + javscript 
$count_array = count($links); // should be 5 for banners;
$ib = 0;
while ($i <= ($count_array - 1)) 
{
?>
$('#<?php echo $links[$i];?>').click(function()
{
<?php
// loop through the other buttons to show images just incase
$ib = 0;
$id = 1;
while ($ib <= ($count_array - 1)) 
{
?>
$('#button_banner_<?php echo  $id; ?>').css("background-image", "url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home-tabs/<?php echo $banner_large_small_images[$ib];?>_smallheader.jpg)");
<?php
$ib++;
$id++;
}
?>

$(this).css("background-image", "none");
// do my image switching logic here.
$('#banner-to-go').fadeTo('slow', 0, function()
{
    $("#banner-text-container").html('<?php echo $banner_content[$i];?>');
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home-tabs/<?php echo $banner_large_small_images[$i];?>_largeheader.jpg)"); }).delay(50).fadeTo('slow', 1);
return false;
});
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
});

})

(jQuery);
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
    // Set the array of banner images //
var imgArr = new Array(
<?php 
// loop through the links
$count_array = count($post_ids); // should be 5 for banners;
$i_links = 0;
while ($i_links < $count_array) 
{
?> 
'<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home-tabs/<?php echo $banner_large_small_images[$i_links];?>_largeheader.jpg'
<?php
// check the comment is needed
    if ($i_links < ($count_array - 1))
    {
    ?>
    ,
    <?php
    }
    $i_links++;
}
?>
);


var contentArr = new Array(
<?php 
// loop through the links
$count_array = count($post_ids); // should be 5 for banners;
$i_links = 0;
while ($i_links < $count_array) 
{
?> 
'<h2><?php echo $links[$i_links];?><br /><span><?php echo $sub_header[$i_links];?></span></h2><p><?php echo $banner_content[$i_links];?></p>'
<?php
// check the comment is needed
    if ($i_links < ($count_array - 1))
    {
    ?>
    ,
    <?php
    }
    $i_links++;
}
?>
);

var hyperArr = new Array(
<?php 
// loop through the links
$count_array = count($post_ids); // should be 5 for banners;
$i_links = 1;
while ($i_links <= $count_array) 
{
?> 
'<?php echo get_permalink($post_ids[$i_links - 1]); ?>'
<?php
// check the comment is needed
    if ($i_links < $count_array)
    {
    ?>
    ,
    <?php
    }
    $i_links++;
}
?>
);

var button_number_Arr = new Array(
1, 2 ,3, 4, 5
);

var preloadArr = new Array();
var preloadHyper = new Array();
var preloadHContent = new Array();
var preloadHButton = new Array();
/* preload images */
var i;
for(i=0; i < imgArr.length; i++){
preloadArr[i] = new Image();
preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];
preloadHyper[i] = hyperArr[i];
preloadHContent[i] = contentArr[i];
preloadHButton[i] = button_number_Arr[i];
}
var currImg = 1;
var currContent = 1;
var currButton = 1;
var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 5000);
/* image rotator */
function changeImg(){
    // Fade out
    $j('#banner-to-go').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function(){
    // Set the content of the banner box
    $j("#banner-text-container").html(preloadHContent[currContent++%preloadArr.length]);
    // Set the buttons to correct the opacity of the css.
    $j('#button_banner_1').css("background-image", "url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home-tabs/<?php echo $banner_large_small_images[0];?>_smallheader.jpg)");
    $j('#button_banner_2').css("background-image", "url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home-tabs/<?php echo $banner_large_small_images[1];?>_smallheader.jpg)");
    $j('#button_banner_3').css("background-image", "url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home-tabs/<?php echo $banner_large_small_images[2];?>_smallheader.jpg)");
    $j('#button_banner_4').css("background-image", "url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home-tabs/<?php echo $banner_large_small_images[3];?>_smallheader.jpg)");
    $j('#button_banner_5').css("background-image", "url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home-tabs/<?php echo $banner_large_small_images[4];?>_smallheader.jpg)");

    $j('#button_banner_' + preloadHButton[currButton++%preloadHButton.length]).css('background-image','none');

    // Set the background image and fade in
    $j('#banner-to-go').css('background','url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +')'); }).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
    return false;
}

});

</script>

<div id="banner-complete-container">

<div id="banner-to-go">
<div id="banner-text-container">

</div>
</div>

<div id="booking-form-generic">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("booking-panel-column") ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div id="banner-lower-menu">
<ul>
<?php
// loop through the values + javscript 
$count_array = count($post_ids); // should be 5 for banners;
$i = 0;
$i2 = 1;
while ($i <= ($count_array - 1)) 
{
?>
<?php //echo $links[$i];?>
<li id="button_banner_<?php echo $i2;?>" style="text-align:center; width:<?php echo $i < 4 ? '20':'19.5'; ?>%; float:left; <?php echo $i < 4 ? 'border-right:solid 1px #FFFFFF;':''; ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_ids[$i]); ?>"><strong><?php echo $links[$i];?></strong><br /><?php echo $sub_header[$i];?></a></li>
<?php
$i++;
$i2++;
}
?>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is a lost cause. You can use [http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/) which is the nivoSlider. When you construct the 'navigation' elements, you can use images for them, so just use the thumbnail image that corresponds to the slide image.

Comment: I thought so - in all honesty I was hoping someone would say that as i'd prefer to rebuild from scratch or use a jQuery slider plugin and modify it. Is it possible to attach a hover event on the Thumbnail nav then with nivoSlider?

Comment: Sure it is. The navigation elements are created by you, and moreover, they're simple DOM elements and can have events attached to them with no issue.

Comment: Since all of this happens on THE CLIENT, your PHP has nothing to do with it and should not be included as part of your question. It just adds noise to your question.

Comment: I apologise for the noise, however I included the whole code as written by the previous developer to show the whole picture and to get feedback on if this solution was the best way to implement a slider with this functionality. I'd prefer a much neater implementation with HTML and jQuery and the feedback I received seems to suggest that is so.